# Can't link fabric app with existing firebase project

Tags: firebase, google-fabric

When trying to link a fabric app to a project I've created in Firebase I receive the following error. I am the owner of the firebase project and the fabric app. Can anyone provide any insight or ideas?

[image]

Comment: You should contact Firebase support directly if you receive an unexpected error in the Firebase console. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson - will post back here if it turns out to be a common problem